# How to sample same 10000 records from two different sources?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two different applications which are running on two different machines.

- Application A is receiving data from Source A.
- Application B is receiving data from Source B.

Technically `Source A` and `Source B` are supposed to provide same data. Source A and B are not controlled by us as it is managed by some other teams.

Now I want to sample records coming from both Source A and B in those two applications. If I am sampling 10000 records from `Source A` then I want to sample same 10000 records from `Source B` as well. I am using `userId` coming from both the source to sample the records. So given a `userId` I need to add some logic by which I can sample 10000 records. And then I will use same logic in both my applications to get same 10000 sampled records from both the source A and B.

We are getting bunch of `userId's` from both the sources and there is no specific pattern for that and I don't know how many userId's I can get in a particular period of time but definitely it is going to be more than 10000. We are getting few million userIds in a day.

What is the algorithm and logic I should use for this so that I can sample 10000 records. I want to use the same logic in both the applications.. Is there any way to do this? I was thinking of using modulus here? I have the exact same below code in both of my applications so I will put the same logic in both of my applications as well.

```
  public void writeToDatabase(final Holder holder) {
    String userId = holder.getUserId();
    // how to make sure that we are storing only 10000 user data in database
    // and it should be same user data from both the system.
    // I was thinking of using hashCode as below but I don't think so it is
    // right way to use it
    if (userId.hashCode() < 10000) {
        // write to database        
    }
  }
```

After storing same data from both the sources (A and B), I need to do some data quality comparisons between those two sources. Basically, I will compare same 10000 `userId` data from Source A with Source B.

Comment: [Reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two problems: 1. How to sample 10,000 records; and 2. How to get the same 10,000 samples with the same userIds from both source A and B.

1. If you are sampling from a file where you know the number of records (let's call it `N`), then you basically sample each record with probability `10000/N`. If you do not know how many records there are (for example, the data could be coming from a stream), then you can apply reservoir sampling. Basically you keep a reservoir of 10,000 records in memory, and of each new record (say, the i'th record), you decide to keep it with probability `10000/i`, and if so, then you kick out a record from the reservoir with probability `1/10000`. The end result is that regardless of the final number for i, each record will get sampled with probability `10000/i`.
2. Whichever approach you use (sampling with known or unknown total), you can get the same results in both applications by setting the random number generator to have the same seed. In Java, just use something like `Random generator = new Random(1)`.

Comment: Can you help me understand how the logic will look like in Java. I have never used reservoir sampling before so I am not sure how will this works out.

Comment: @shortcut: Just follow the pseudocode of "Algorithm R" in the Wikipedia article on reservoir sampling. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Algorithm_R  . You can also just google "reservoir sampling java" to find implementations.

Comment: I found a sample example [here](https://github.com/twitter/commons/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/common/stats/ReservoirSampler.java). Is this what you meant? Now how can I use this for my use case? Any thoughts?

Comment: @shortcut: The `sample(item)` function in that code seems to be the key method. Basically you would have your own code to acquire a new record; let's say that you call your function `Item myItem = getNext();`. This could be a call to a database or a data stream for your case. Then call `sample(myItem)`, which looks like it runs all the reservoir sampling logic for you. When you have run out of items, the code looks like you can call `getSamples()` to get the final list of items.

Comment: @shortcut: Yes, that's right. call `sample(userId)` repeatedly for as many records as you want. When you finally want to get all 10,000 samples, you should apparently call `getSamples()`.

Comment: so you are saying, I will keep populating all the userId's to this class and then at the end I will call a method `getSamples()` to give me all the 10000 `userId's`? In my case, I am getting `userId` and its data from a particular source already so at that time I need to decide whether I should save this `userId` or not so it has to be on the fly as soon as that `userId` comes to my above `writeToDatabase` method. As soon as any userId comes to `writeToDatabase` method, at that time I need to decide whether I should save this userId or not.

Comment: According to the reservoir sampling algorithm, an item can enter the reservoir, but it can be kicked out if a later item is chosen to be sampled and the reservoir is full. In your case, you should create the item so that it contains both the `userId` as well as the related data. Alternatively, you will have to restructure the rest of your code so that it will work with a list of `userId` after all the sampling is done.